# Multiselect picklist values are not prepopulating while clone using custom button URLFOR

Tags: lightning, custom-button, urlhacking, multi-select, urlfor

Created custom button and added on page layout in lightning i want to clone specific fields only so using url hack.

```
      {!URLFOR('/lightning/o/Request__c/new?&recordTypeId=0129C000009CIiu&defaultFieldValues=
      Name__c='+(Request_Name__c.Name__c)
     +IF( ISBLANK(Request__c.Knowledge_Data__c) , '',',Knowledge_Data__c='+Request__c.Knowledge_Data__c )
```

Here **Request__c.Knowledge_Data__c field is multi select picklist**. When i am saving this it is showing error

> Error: Field Request__c.Knowledge_Data__c is a multi-select picklist
> field. Multi-select picklist fields are only supported in certain
> functions. Tell me more

Answer (score 0):

The problem is NOT with `ISBLANK` func, but at the end of the formula (this part: `+Request__c.Knowledge_Data__c` while trying to access the multi-select picklist value). Multi-select picklists are weird and using them in formula has many limitations. The following part of your formula:

`IF( ISBLANK(Request__c.Knowledge_Data__c) , '',',Knowledge_Data__c='+Request__c.Knowledge_Data__c )`

has to be done in the following format:

`LEFT(<Extract Multi-select picklist value>,  LEN(<Extract Multi-select picklist value>)-1)`

Assuming the multi-select picklist has 2 values (One & Two), the formula would be
`LEFT(IF(ISBLANK(Request__c.Knowledge_Data__c), '', IF(INCLUDES(Request__c.Knowledge_Data__c, "One"), "One;", "") & IF(INCLUDES(Request__c.Knowledge_Data__c, "Two"), "Two;", "")),  LEN(IF(ISBLANK(Request__c.Knowledge_Data__c), '', IF(INCLUDES(Request__c.Knowledge_Data__c, "One"), "One;", "") & IF(INCLUDES(Request__c.Knowledge_Data__c, "Two"), "Two;", "")))-1)`

Note:

- The `LEFT` function is used to discard the last `;`.
- If the multi-select picklist has many values or frequently changing values, then using formula is not really a good approach. Create another field that is updated by before trigger or record triggered flow (before) and use the same in the formula.